# How to listen to realtime database changes (like a stream) in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to listen to the changes in a specific field in a specific document in Firebase Realtime database. I am using Node JS for the cloud functions. this is the function.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);


const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

exports.condOnUpdate = functions.database.ref('data/').onWrite(async snapshot=> {

    const snapBefore = snapshot.before;
    const snapAfter = snapshot.after;
    const dataB = snapBefore.val();
    const data = snapAfter.val();
    const prev= dataB['cond'];
    const curr= data['cond'];

    // terminate if there is no change
    if(prev==curr)
    {
        return;
    }


    if(curr==0){
        // send notifications every 10 seconds until value becomes 1
         while(true){
            admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload);
            await delay(10000);
        }
    }else if(curr==1){
        // send one notification
        admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload);
        return;
    }

});
```

The function works as expected but the loop never stops as it never exists the loop, instead, the function runs again (with new instance I suppose).

so is there any way to listen to the data changes in one function just like streams in other languages, or perhaps stop all cloud functions from running.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sinc eyou're doing `while(true){`, the infinite loop is somewhat expected isn't it?

Comment: Exactly but i want to stop it when the same function get called again and curr val becomes 1

Comment: Since nothing in the code you shared updates `curr`, that will never happen. Is this code supposed to update the `curr` field somewhere? Or does that happen from somewhere else, outside of this function.

Comment: yes, the value is getting updated with a sensor. I have tried a solution where I have added a boolean flag to determine if the function is running or not, and it seems to be working just fine. Though I am not sure if there is a more efficient solution for this scenario.

Comment: If the document is updated from outside of this Cloud Function, then that update will trigger another instance of the function. If won't update the `curr` value in your existing instance of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems that the `cond` property is updated from outside of the Cloud Function. When that happens, it will trigger a new instance of the Cloud Function to run with its own `curr` variable, but it won't cause the `curr` value in the current instance to be updated. So the `curr` variable in the original instance of your code will never become true, and it will continue to run until it times out.

---

If you want the current instance to detect the change to the property, you will need to monitor that property inside the code too by calling `onValue` on a reference to it.

An easier approach though might be to use a [interval trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) rather than a database trigger to:

- have code execute every minute, and then in there
- query the database with the relevant `cond` value, and then
- send a notification to each of those.

This requires no endless loop or timeouts in your code, which is typically a better approach when it comes to Cloud Functions.